# Projecting geometry features upside down using MapServer

Tags: shapefile, mapserver

I have shapefiles containing polygons and lines that are used in a mapfile for projecting them through Mapserver.

Is there a way in changing the projection of the layers by 180 degrees (i.e. upside down)?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to rotate all of your layers, this can easily be accomplished by using the ANGLE attribute of the MAP object.

MAP
      ANGLE 180

Take a look at this wiki page for more info:  http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/MapRotation

There are also some good caveats in the mapfile documentation:  http://mapserver.org/mapfile/map.html#ANGLE

For instance, if you specify a layer angle, it will be calculated relative to the map angle.

Comment: I've followed the instructions and inserted a PROJECTION object in the MAP object as well as in the LAYER objects and it displays the map NOT upside down(or in the mirror as I would say). Furthermore, it blows all the panning and zooming now. Whenever I try to zoom in the features simply disappear (well, they're down and I have to pan to find them) and when I get to see them with panning upon reload they disappear(move down) again. I have not changed the extent or anything, but simply introduced the sample PROJECTION object attributes from the mapfile documentation.

Comment: It sounds like you are using some sort of client to view the requests to MapServer.  What do you get if you send a basic mode=map request to MapServer or use shp2img?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, I *think* this will work. If the map projection you're using has a scale factor, make it negative. If the false easting and false northing values are non-zero, make them negative too.

I haven't used MapServer so I don't know if it's possible or the details on how to do it.

Comment: found the scaling factor parameter you're talking about. http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms but in the projection object I inserted the factor is missing.if I were to insert the factor, what value should I assign to it? (be it negative as you suggested)

Comment: -1.0. It's possible that the projection implementation won't understand what to do with the parameter.

Comment: i tried it for the projection inside the map object as well as within the layer definitions. Got: Projection library error. k <= 0 and no projection at all. :(